# how to get data from jsonb column in postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a database which have a `table`.There are two columns in my table `id` ,and description of type `jsonb` now I want to fetch all `name` in table.how to do that

I tried like this but not working

```
SELECT description::jsonb->name FROM Category
```

[image]

**expected output**

```
["hello","test","world"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation: `json[b]_agg()` can be used to generate a json array made of all `'name'` attributes of the original objects, ordered by `id`.

```
select jsonb_agg(description ->> 'name' order by id) res from category
```

Note that, since `description` is of `jsonb` datatype to start with, there is no need for an additional cast.

Comment: yes it working fine ..!! thank for help . I need one more small help .can I show only those whose `name` is `test` ?

Comment: using this link I found something https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Comment: can I use this `jsonb_extract_path_text `

Comment: to find only which have name `test`

Comment: can I use this to filter the table ?

Comment: @user944513 `select jsonb_agg(description ->> 'name' order by id) res from category where (description ->> 'name')='test'`

Comment: so where i will use this `jsonb_extract_path_text `

Comment: see documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Comment: You don't need to use `jsonb_extract_path_text`.

Comment: @user944513: as explained by AdamKG, if you want to filter the table based on the value of an attribute, you can just use the  `->>` operator; `where description ->> 'name' ='test'` is just what you need.